# More condition under floating filter model instead of only two filters using ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Need to add one more condition under text filter model. Currently its only allow me filter the data using only two conditions and I am expecting one more extra condition. How to add extract textbox with AND OR option.

[image]

Comment: and what did you do so far? please share with us some code snippets or any efforts to help other members find your answer better.

Comment: @novonimo i am still exploring and also posted in ag-grid forum this. There is no solution yet found.

Comment: hope to get your answer soon. good luck 